# How to fix 'I can't get values from function to .html

Tags: html, ionic3

I want to take the value from the function, then display it in .html. I use this, but not work `{{this.object}}`

### .html

```
 <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Titik" [(ngModel)]="this.object"></ion-input>
```

### .ts

```
function OkE(){
     console.log(this.name);
    }
     const myObj = {
     name: 'just an object',
     status: 'idle',
    };
    this.object = OkE.apply(myObj);
```

Comment: try without this

Comment: Thank you reply..still the same, it doesn't work [(ngModel)]="object"

Comment: can u please describe more about ur function and which value u want to display

Comment: ahaa ... :) i want to learn ionic, now i have a problem getting a location point on the leaflet map when i click it. With my little ability, i assume this function is the same way to apply to my case. Suppose, this.name (just an object) is a point object that can display the value in <ion-input> .html when the map leaflet is clicked ... that's it. Correct me if it's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. Use the property `value`

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Titik" [(ngModel)]="object" [value]="object"></ion-input>
```

### .ts file

```
function OkE(){
 console.log(this.name);
}
 const myObj = {
 name: 'just an object',
 status: 'idle',
};
this.object = OkE.apply(myObj);
```

Comment: Thank you,.actually when using this OkE.apply (myObj);
then the results will be "just an object" in console.log,
but i want to be able to .html.. stil no luck, I've tried your way

Comment: What do you want to bind ?

Comment: Please sir, see the details of my next question ...below